# Derivative of an integral with regard to a different variable

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

Assume I have the following expression:

$$\int_0^x f(t,\theta) dt$$

where $t$ (or $x$) and $\theta$ are some vector-valued variables, and $f$ is some function which does not permit an easy analytical solution to the integral (But can be approximated numerically). Assume now that I seek the partial derivative $\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}=[\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta_1},...,\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta_N}]^T$ of this expression, i.e.:

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}\int_0^x f(t,\theta) dt$$

How can I solve this? Is it possible to approach the solution like this: (?)

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}\int_0^x f(t,\theta) dt=\int_0^x \frac{\partial f(t,\theta)}{\partial \theta} dt$$

If not, is there a different way to solve this?

Comment: Related: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule#General_form:_Differentiation_under_the_integral_sign

Comment: @Keshav: that's an interesting link, thank you. In my case, however, $t$ and $\theta$ are independent.

Comment: $x$ and $t$ are independent in the article.

Comment: This is the famous Feynman trick, also called differentiating under the integral sign.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the integration is with respect to $t$ and its limits are independent of $\theta$, your approach is correct in this particular case. Derivation and integration are both linear operators and follow the general rules of the interchangeability of linear operators.